# Sinatra doesn't load when running a ruby app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I'm trying to run a Ruby application that requires Sinatra within Ubuntu 10.10. I'm new to the 3 of these technologies so I understand if this question looks dumb to you.

Yesterday I installed ruby doing...
    `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full`

And sinatra by doing...
    `sudo gem install sinatra`

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    "Hi Alex!"
end
```

When I do `ruby1.9.1 -rubygems app.rb` nothing happens (Ruby is properly installed since I tried running apps that don't require sinatra and they work OK).

```
$ ls
app.rb
$ 
$ ruby1.9.1 app.rb
$
$ ruby1.9.1 -rubygems app.rb
$
```

I know it should open Sinatra and tell me which port it is listening to.

I've been looking for help through the web and read several of the threads created within this forum but nothing I've tried has worked out for me.

What could be happening here?

Thanks

Comment: What specifically are you getting? You run that command and literally nothing happens?

Comment: Did you install sinatra gem without any problem ?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but note that in Ruby 1.9 you don't need to require rubygems specifically, neither on the command line nor in your scripts.

Comment: @Mike Lewis: I'm getting absolutely nothing. The output I copied is everything I receive.

Comment: @Mike: as far as I know, which is not really that far, it was installed without any problem. Just to verify I did the following...

`$ sudo gem install sinatra
Successfully installed sinatra-1.2.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sinatra-1.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for sinatra-1.2.3...
$ ruby1.9.1 app.rb
$`

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks. I had read about that but I added it to the code anyway not to make a newbie mistake.

Comment: There was a similar problem with sinatra 1.0 on ruby 1.9.2. The answer there was to add `enable :run` to your code, it could be worth trying that (I can't get a version of 1.9.1 to compile to test if it myself).

Comment: @matt: oh boy. I added that to the code and worked just fine. I spent a whole day in trying to sort this problem out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Menfiesto have a look here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_the_builtin_web_server - if you're going to be deploying to a server you'll want to do something like `enable :run if __FILE__ == $0` so that you only start the built in server when you need it. (You might want to check for the version of ruby in use too if you're deploying to another machine). It might be worth looking into whether you can upgrade to 1.9.2 as well.

Comment: @matt You should post that as an answer so that it can be accepted and help future people with similar problems. Nice work.

Comment: @matt: I'll take a look to that. Thanks again. Please add your response as an answer so I can mark it as useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a similar problem with sinatra 1.0 on ruby 1.9.2. The answer there was to add `enable :run` to your code.

Have a look at the [docs for the `:run` configuration](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_the_builtin_web_server) - if you're going to be deploying to a server you'll want to do something like `enable :run if __FILE__ == $0` so that you only start the built-in server during development when you need it.

Strictly speaking your code is correct and should run okay, and in fact it does with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. <strike>The problem seems to be running it with ruby 1.9.1. In general 1.9.1 seems to be fairly outdated and you should probably look to upgrade to 1.9.2 if you can. If Ubuntu doesn't have any packages for 1.9.2 take a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io).</strike> (In fact if you're going to be doing ruby development rvm is worth a look anyway).

---

#### Update:

I managed to get ruby 1.9.1 compiled to test this, and your code worked ok. Also a bit of googling suggests that the [Ubuntu ruby1.9.1 package provides ruby 1.9.2 anyway](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ruby1.9.1). So there seems to be something else going on causing `:run` not to be set when running the file directly, though I don't know what that could be.

#### Another update:

Looking at the [Ubuntu Sinatra package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libsinatra-ruby1.9.1) it looks like it's at version 1.0. It could be that your setup is using the Ubuntu
package and ignoring the more recent version installed via rubygems. This could explain what's happening. If so this isn't a "a similar problem" to ruby 1.9 and sinatra 1.0 like I suggested above, it's the same problem!

#### Yet another update:

A couple of things have occurred to me. You can check what version of Sinatra you're actually using with something like `puts Sinatra::VERSION` after  `require 'sinatra'`. Also, it looks like [there is a `gem1.9.1` command](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/i386/ruby1.9.1/filelist) that corresponds to `ruby1.9.1`. It looks like when you installed sinatra with `sudo gem install sinatra` the latest version got installed into the ruby 1.8 install, and left ruby 1.9 with the Ubuntu packaged Sinatra 1.0. If you haven't switched over to rvm yet, you could try `sudo gem1.9.1 install sinatra`.

Comment: Thanks again! As I said before, your solution worked OK.

I'm now reading about rvm and it appears to be very useful. Thanks for this too...

Comment: @Menfiesto I don't know if my edit will cause a notification in your inbox. If not this comment is just to draw your attention to it.

Comment: thanks once again. This info you gave me was very useful for some other gems I'm dealing with.